# Print datagrid values

Tags: c#, grid, printing

in C# win app i displayed the data's in datagridview, in that i need to print the datagrid values same form without using report or crystal report if any codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop throught all rows and collumns then send it to the printer?

Comment: If i put the loop means the values are send to some other forms or some other datagrid i couldn't print the value

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) class and associated classes. You'll have to loop through your data and draw it to each page using GDI+ calls on each page's Graphics instance.

I don't envy your task. If you provide some concrete information I can help more, perhaps with some example code, but a highly generalized question will receive highly generalized answers.